# How do I find the file and row number in which the definition of a python object is written?

Tags: python, file, path

E.g. for:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array(1)
```

I know that the array function is part of the numpy module. However, numpy is quite big, hence is there a way to find the exact file where the array function is implemented?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using visual studio code. Put the mouse one the word, press ctrl and click when it's blue.

It works for me at least.

Comment: Thanks. But is there a python function to do this, e.g. via the terminal?

Comment: This definitely isn't going to work with `numpy`